# How to write query to compare difference between two timestamps with a timeinterval

Tags: java, jpa, timestamp

I am trying to pull out records based on some comparison between two timstamps. here is my supposed code, but it is not working:

```
 @Query("SELECT n FROM table1 n  WHERE n.status IN ('FAILED') AND  :currentDate-    n.updatedDate > n.interval/24*60*60")

List<Entity> findAllSuchEntities(@Param("currentDate") DateTime currentDate);
```

The error message is : org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unknown data type: "?"; SQL statement.

In comparison, following query can pass compilation:

```
 @Query("SELECT n FROM table1 n  WHERE n.status IN ('FAILED') AND  :currentDate > n.updatedDate")

List<Entity> findAllSuchEntities(@Param("currentDate") DateTime currentDate);
```

Comment: tried brackets around the ":currentDate - n.updatedDate" ? And if comparing with some H2 error message please actually state what SQL was used

Comment: What is n.interval in the first query? Can you show the formats of the dates?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Query("SELECT n FROM table1 n WHERE n.status IN ('FAILED') AND n.updatedDate < (:currentDate - (n.interval/24*60*60))")
```

It is also a better solution as your previous query will most likely cause a full table scan.

Comment: I tried this approach, here is the error message: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2014-10-03T15:21:30.527-05:00] was not matching type [java.lang.Long].         Any suggestion?